# How to run an executable from flutter package without activating it globally?

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I want to write a script to call [flutter_gen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gen) package from CLI using `fluttergen -c pubspec.yaml` command. But the only way I know to do it is run `dart pub global activate flutter_gen` firstly.

This approach requires the user of my script to ensure that `/.pub-cache/bin` directory is added to PATH. To prevent such extra work, I want to find a way to run it "locally" (i.e. without global activation).

For know I use this bad workaround:

```bash
dart pub global activate flutter_gen
fluttergen -c pubspec.yaml
dart pub global deactivate flutter_gen
```

How can I run `fluttergen -c pubspec.yaml` command without `dart pub global activate flutter_gen` command?

Answer (score 0):

To run a global dart package, you can follow the example from the dart documentation

```bash
dart pub global run foo:bar arg1 arg2
```

foo is the name of the package

bar is the name of the file you want to run

and the arg1 arg2 are the command arguments your package will use

in your case the command might be as following

```bash
dart pub global run flutter_gen:main
```

assuming the entry file is the main file

```bash
dart pub global run flutter_gen:main --help
```

assuming it the command has the help argument

Looking at the [Flutter Gen repository](https://github.com/FlutterGen/flutter_gen), I am not sure what should be the correct file to run and the library documentation doesn't specify either.

[The oficial dart documentation about this](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-using-dart-pub-global-run)

Comment: Trying this gives me a "No active package <x>" so I think this still requires a global activation.

Comment: running `dart pub global activate flutter_gen` is always needed since that is the installation

Comment: perhaps I'm misreading what the OP wanted, but as I proposed, adding it with `flutter pub add` it can be run in the folder after running `flutter pub get` without having to install it as a global command.

Answer (score 0):

Try running just `dart run flutter_gen`. You will have to add it as a dependency first though.